# Call method from another component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components

How do I call the method from another component in this scenario? I would like to load additional pice of data from the API once the button is clicked in the component 1 to the component 2.

Thanks

Here are my two components in the seperate files:

compbutton.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a href v-on:click="buttonClicked">Change Name</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'compbutton',
        methods: {
            buttonClicked: function () {
                //call changeName here
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

compname.vue

```
<template>
    <div>{{name}}</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'compname',
        data: function () {
            return {
                name: 'John'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeName: function () {
                this.name = 'Ben'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Store the data in a parent. Pass that data down to compname.vue as a prop. Make compbutton.vue emit an event on click, which the parent listens to. Change the data in the parent. compname.vue will receive the updated value.

Comment: Could you show me on my example?

Comment: Can you try implementing my suggestion first? I'll be glad to help after that. Here's the relevant docs. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props |   https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events

Comment: @Ben is compbutton.vue the parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **service** as a go-between. Usually, services are used to share data but in javascript functions can be treated like data also.

The service code is trivial, just add a stub for the function `changeName`

**changeName.service.js**

```js
export default {
  changeName: function () {}
}
```

To have services injected into the components, you need to include **vue-injector** in the project.

```
npm install --save vue-inject
or
yarn add vue-inject
```

and have a register of services,

**injector-register.js**

```js
import injector from 'vue-inject';

import ChangeNameService from '@/services/changeName.service'

injector.service('changeNameService', function () { 
  return ChangeNameService 
});
```

then in `main.js` (or main file may be called index.js), a section to initialize the injector.

```js
import injector from 'vue-inject';
require('@/services/injector-register');
Vue.use(injector);
```

Finally, add the service to the component `dependencies` array, and use the service

**compname.vue**

```js
<script>
  export default {
    dependencies : ['changeNameService'],
    created() {
      // Set the service stub function to point to this one
      this.changeNameService.changeName = this.changeName;
    },
    ...
```

**compbutton.vue**

```js
<script>
  export default {
    dependencies : ['changeNameService'],
    name: 'compbutton',
    methods: {
       buttonClicked: function () {
         this.changeNameService.changeName();
       }
    }
    ...
```

Add a `#` to the button href to stop page reloads

```html
<a href="#" v-on:click="buttonClicked">Change Name</a>
```

See the whole thing in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/88230ok419)

Comment: It is indeed, I tend to find that with Vue - simple bits but in a lot of places. Injection is the officially correct way to do it (I feel obliged to present the pattern), but you might find it works with simple imports of the service as well. Don't forget, injection makes unit testing go a lot easier.

Answer (score 6):

You can name the component and then $ref to the method from another componenent.

compbutton.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a href v-on:click="buttonClicked">Change Name</a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "compbutton",
  methods: {
    buttonClicked: function() {
      //call changeName here
      this.$root.$refs.compname_component.changeName();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

compname.vue

```
<template>
  <div>{{name}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "compname",
  data: function() {
    return {
      name: "John"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeName: function() {
      this.name = "Ben";
    }
  },
  created() {
    // set componenent name
    this.$root.$refs.compname_component = this;
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative answer: you can pass the function you want *the child to invoke* as a *prop **from** the parent component*. Using your example:

compbutton.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a href v-on:click="buttonClicked">Change Name</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'compbutton',
        props: {
            clickHandler: {
                type: Function,
                default() {
                    return function () {};
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            buttonClicked: function () {
                this.clickHandler(); // invoke func passed via prop
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

compname.vue

```
<template>
    <div>{{name}}</div>
    <compbutton :click-handler="changeName"></compbutton>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'compname',
        data: function () {
            return {
                name: 'John'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeName: function () {
                this.name = 'Ben'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note, in your example, it doesn't appear where you want the 'compbutton' component to be rendered, so in the template for compname.vue, thats been added as well.